# Can I change GlusterFS replica 3 to replica 3 with arbiter 1?

Tags: glusterfs

I configured a volume as a replica 3 and now I want to convert it to a replica 3 with arbiter 1.

I cannot seem to locate any information on if this is possible or if I need to move my data, destroy the volume and recreate it.

I am running glusterfs 4.1.4

```
Volume Name: clustered_sites
Type: Replicate
Volume ID: 34ef4f5b-497a-443c-922b-b168729ac1c6
Status: Started
Snapshot Count: 0
Number of Bricks: 1 x 3 = 3
Transport-type: tcp
Bricks:
Brick1: www-one-internal:/mnt/clustered_sites/brick1
Brick2: www-two-internal:/mnt/clustered_sites/brick1
Brick3: www-three-internal:/mnt/clustered_sites/brick1
Options Reconfigured:
cluster.consistent-metadata: on
performance.client-io-threads: off
nfs.disable: on
transport.address-family: inet
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can. Ensure that there are no pending heals before you do so.

```
gluster volume remove-brick clustered_sites replica 2 www-three-internal:/mnt/clustered_sites/brick1 force

gluster volume add-brick clustered_sites replica 3 arbiter 1 www-three-internal:/mnt/clustered_sites/new_arbiter_brick
```

Comment: Thank You for the help! I ended up using the following commands to make the change: `gluster volume remove-brick clustered_sites replica 2 www-three-internal:/mnt/clustered_sites/brick1 force` and `gluster volume add-brick clustered_sites replica 3 arbiter 1 www-three-internal:/mnt/clustered_sites/new_arbiter_brick`

Comment: Ah sorry,  I put the volume name in the wrong place in the command.

Comment: Please cancel my editing suggestion. Was a mistake. Thank you.

Comment: @OscarGarcia I think it is better to have the right syntax in the answer itself. I accepted your edit.